# Is anti-world building on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I'm intending to ask a question, where it is about to proof, that such a world could NOT exist.

Would this be on topic here?
If so, what tag should I use?

Comment: You could probably just propose the supposed impossible world and use [tag:reality-check]. People seem to really enjoy explaining how other people's ideas would never work.

Answer (score 3):

Generally yes, but keep in mind that proving a negative is probably going to be too broad. And furthermore, with magic anything is possible.

Comment: Well its more like disprooving a world on a matter of science based if not hard science. so that shouldn't be a problem I guess?

Comment: Well proving a negative is still very hard. Note that you could use the [sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/635/9685) to get a direct feedback on your question.